# Avoid loading all related records when performing a query on relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Hi have a many to one relationship between HistoricData (many) to HistoricDataGroup (one) as defined in the function "data" in the model below:

class HistoricDataGroup extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

```
protected $fillable = ["name", "token", "description"];

public function data()
{
    return $this->hasMany("App\Models\HistoricData");
}

public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function ($group) {
        $group->data()->delete();
        $group->workingData()->delete();
    });
}
```

}

In my controller function, I want to fetch the fields from HistoricDataGroup and some records from its related HistoricData model depending on there where clause applied to that data, and then return as json.

```
public function showChunk(Request $request)
{
    $historic_data_group = HistoricDataGroup::find($request->id);
    $result["group"] = $historic_data_group;
    $result["data"] = $historic_data_group->data->where(
        "id",
        "<",
        $request->candle_id
    );
    return response()->json($result);
 }
```

However, the data appears twice in the $result as all the related records are included as well as the filtered related data, as shown in the dd($result) screenshot below:

[image]

Is there a way to execute this without loading all the related records?

Comment: you are loading the relationship when you access the dynamic property, don't use the dynamic property and do the query on the relationship itself to filter `$something = $historic_data_group->data()->where(...)->get()`

Comment: @lagbox thanks that was the issue, I could accept that if you make that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access the dynamic property for a relationship it will attempt to load the relationship if it is not already loaded. Loaded relationships are included in the serialized output.

You could directly query the relationship object to avoid loading the relationship:

```
$data = $historic_data_group->data()->where(...)->get();
```

Or if you want to use the dynamic property (lets say the relationship was already loaded previously) you can unset the relationship before the model is serialized:

```
$historic_data_group->unsetRelation('data');
```

This will remove it from the serialized output because it wouldn't be loaded any more. There is also the option of 'hiding' the relationship or using a transformer for your response, like an ApiResource, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Eloquent resources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources) to format what you send to the front-end.

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class HistoricDataGroupResource extends JsonResource
{
   public function toArray($request)
   {
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        // Map your other table data 
        
   }
}
```

in your controller

```
public function showChunk(Request $request)
{
   $historic_data_group = HistoricDataGroup::find($request->id);
   $data = $historic_data_group->data()->where("id", "<",$request->candle_id)->get();
       return response()->json([
          'group'=> \App\Http\Resources\HistoricDataGroupResource::make($historic_data_group),
          'data'=>$data
    ]);
  }
```